# laravel query builder for multiple whereIn() with or condition instead of deault and condition

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

Laravel query builder for multiple whereIn() statements with or condition instead of deault and condition

```
$meetings = DB::table('googlesheet')->whereIn('rollnumber1',$qTXT)->whereIn('rollnumber2',$qTXT)->whereIn('rollnumber3',$qTXT)->whereIn('rollnumber4',$qTXT)->toSql();
```

Uses 'and' but I need 'or' condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add [`or`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L735) as the third parameter.

```
$meetings = DB::table('googlesheet')->whereIn('rollnumber1',$qTXT, 'or')->whereIn('rollnumber2',$qTXT, 'or')->whereIn('rollnumber3',$qTXT, 'or')->whereIn('rollnumber4',$qTXT, 'or')->toSql();
```

Or you can use [`orWhereIn()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L783)

```
$meetings = DB::table('googlesheet')->whereIn('rollnumber1',$qTXT)->orWhereIn('rollnumber2',$qTXT)->orWhereIn('rollnumber3',$qTXT)->orWhereIn('rollnumber4',$qTXT)->toSql();
```

Comment: Thanks Dess, it worked with orWhereIn(). Thank you for the support

Comment: @GurubilleSrinivasReddy mark this answer as the answer if it solves the question